# How to set up the same Docker cache behavior during build on Ubuntu as it is on Windows?

Tags: linux, windows, docker, caching, build

We have such `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM alpine:latest as step1
RUN echo "STEP1"

FROM alpine:latest as step2
RUN echo "STEP2"

FROM step1 as step3
RUN echo "STEP3"
```

On Windows (or on WSL2) we have such results for building multi-stage images.

Building all steps on Windows:

```
$ docker build .
[+] Building 0.2s (7/7) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 32B                                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                            0.1s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                              0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/alpine:latest                                                                                                             0.0s
 => [step1 1/2] FROM docker.io/library/alpine:latest                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => CACHED [step1 2/2] RUN echo "STEP1"                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => CACHED [step3 1/1] RUN echo "STEP3"                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => exporting to image                                                                                                                                                       0.1s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => => writing image sha256:38ba33425558f5373099ad59aa187456c38b3f5eab14a60fdbb3cb7b1c484392                                                                                 0.0s

Use 'docker scan' to run Snyk tests against images to find vulnerabilities and learn how to fix them
```

Building Step 2 on Windows:

```
$ docker build --target step2 .
[+] Building 0.5s (6/6) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 32B                                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                            0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                              0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/alpine:latest                                                                                                             0.0s
 => CACHED [step2 1/2] FROM docker.io/library/alpine:latest                                                                                                                  0.0s
 => [step2 2/2] RUN echo "STEP2"                                                                                                                                             0.3s
 => exporting to image                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => => writing image sha256:855f35039a5a902e1d33111fc781f748955f8b3cad7fb56d6eb420fc5d2fa55b                                                                                 0.0s

Use 'docker scan' to run Snyk tests against images to find vulnerabilities and learn how to fix them
```

Docker version on Windows:

```
$ docker version
Client:
 Cloud integration: 1.0.17
 Version:           20.10.7
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.16.4
 Git commit:        f0df350
 Built:             Wed Jun  2 12:00:56 2021
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.7
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.13.15
  Git commit:       b0f5bc3
  Built:            Wed Jun  2 11:54:58 2021
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.4.6
  GitCommit:        d71fcd7d8303cbf684402823e425e9dd2e99285d
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc95
  GitCommit:        b9ee9c6314599f1b4a7f497e1f1f856fe433d3b7
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```

While on Ubuntu we have slightly **different** results.

Building all steps on Ubuntu:

```
$ docker build .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/6 : FROM alpine:latest as step1
 ---> d4ff818577bc
Step 2/6 : RUN echo "STEP1"
 ---> Using cache
 ---> ca7b2711269c
Step 3/6 : FROM alpine:latest as step2
 ---> d4ff818577bc
Step 4/6 : RUN echo "STEP2"
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 50668d3ea1c2
Step 5/6 : FROM step1 as step3
 ---> ca7b2711269c
Step 6/6 : RUN echo "STEP3"
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f529239cd29a
Successfully built f529239cd29a
```

Building Step 2 on Ubuntu:

```
$ docker build --target step2 .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/4 : FROM alpine:latest as step1
 ---> d4ff818577bc
Step 2/4 : RUN echo "STEP1"
 ---> Using cache
 ---> ca7b2711269c
Step 3/4 : FROM alpine:latest as step2
 ---> d4ff818577bc
Step 4/4 : RUN echo "STEP2"
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 50668d3ea1c2
Successfully built 50668d3ea1c2
```

Docker version on Ubuntu:

```
$ docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           20.10.7
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.13.15
 Git commit:        f0df350
 Built:             Wed Jun  2 11:56:38 2021
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.7
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.13.15
  Git commit:       b0f5bc3
  Built:            Wed Jun  2 11:54:50 2021
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.4.6
  GitCommit:        d71fcd7d8303cbf684402823e425e9dd2e99285d
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc95
  GitCommit:        b9ee9c6314599f1b4a7f497e1f1f856fe433d3b7
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```

As you can see Docker Desktop (Windows) **skips unneeded stages** while Docker on Ubuntu builds them. The Docker Engine versions are the same.

For complex multi-stage images, the caching behavior the Docker on Windows can save a lot of build time comparing to the one on Ubuntu.

How to make Docker on Ubuntu behave the same way with cache as on Windows?

Comment: The cache on two different machines can be populated differently. You may have built different images on the machine prior to trying to build those same two images. To really compare like with like you would need to clear the caches of both machines first. Either way ... why do you care how good the caching was - you should just be looking to get the same image in both cases and leave the caching/optimisation to the detail of the docker exectuable.

Comment: When the Ubuntu (non-buildkit) output says `Using cache` it's also skipping the step.  If you want to demonstrate this further, try changing one of the steps to `RUN sleep 5` and see whether it sleeps or not.

Comment: The problem here that I do not what to build the unneeded stage at all.

Comment: For example, if stage2 had command `COPY / /app` then if files are changed in the folder then the stage2 will be rebuilt on Ubuntu no matter of cache. On Windows, it will be skipped — the correct behavior.

Comment: @DavidMaze, let’s do changes like below:

```
FROM alpine:latest as step1
RUN echo "STEP1"

FROM alpine:latest as step2
RUN sleep 10

FROM step1 as step3
RUN echo "STEP3"
```

and run the build without caching by `docker build --no-cache .`

The build on Windows will be ~1 second while on Ubuntu — over 10 seconds.

Comment: ...so Windows is ignoring the `--no-cache` option?  That sounds like a Docker bug.

Comment: Windows does not igrnore `--no-cache` option. It skips unneeded stage.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer by myself. On Ubuntu we need to enable BuildKit by `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1`. See https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#buildkit

In this case, the behavior on both platforms is the same.